# Java not smoothing custom fonts

Tags: java, fonts, antialiasing, smoothing

Me and my group are creating a web applet (entirely applet). However, I created a custom font to use for a banner but it won't use anti aliasing/font smoothing on it.
All the other normal fonts used work just fine but my custom font refuses to.

I'm using an opentype windows ttf font called FoundryMonoline.

```
    try {
        fontAd = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("D:\\ATWDemo\\src\\FoundMonMed.ttf"));
    } catch (FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    fontAd = fontAd.deriveFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 22);

    SimpleAttributeSet sa = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setAlignment(sa, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);

                    text_title.getStyledDocument().setParagraphAttributes(0,text_title.getStyledDocument().getLength(),sa,false);

    text_title.setFont(fontAd);
```